# Reverse Engineer Joomla fabrik calculator

Tags: javascript, websites

I am wondering if it is possible to reverse engineer the calculator on this url:

http://www.contrelec.co.uk/index.php/en/motor-full-load-current-estimator-kw

It appears to be a Joomla site with the Fabrik plugin driving the calculator. Some research suggests Fabrik uses Ajax, a language I know little about other than it is client-side calculation, so the source should be accessible(?)

Glad of anyone's help.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the owner for the script (i.e. me)?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Reverse Engineering! Unfortunately, RE is not a forum, and the "Answer" box is for *answers* only. This could have a comment; once you have a bit of reputation, you can comment on posts. If you want to [edit] this into a proper answer, you can do so; else, it will probably get flagged for deletion.

Comment: @user262170 are you serious? Apparently no provision for private messages on stackexchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: @user262170 however I'd love to get my hands on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is on the server-side (and executed via an HTTP POST to http://www.contrelec.co.uk/index.php/en/motor-full-load-current-estimator-kw), so you won't be able to directly extract the algorithm by just looking at the client-side HTML, JavaScript, etc.

However, since there are only 3 input variables, it shouldn't be too difficult to write a program to submit many values, extract the output, and then extrapolate the formula by graphing the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason, any pointers as to how to substitute values in programmatically?

Comment: That would be a question for http://stackoverflow.com/